# Setting Struts2 <s:select> options Css Class

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts2, struts-tags

I am working on an application that is built on struts 2.5.17. I have `<s:select>` tag with option groups and options. I am trying to add cssClass to options under option groups. I am trying to add css class to options using listCssClass attribute of `<s:select>` but it is not adding class to the options. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is code from my JSP:

```
<s:select
            list="#{'none':'--Select Template--'}"
            id="export-data"
            cssStyle="width:250px;"
            title="templateDesc"
            cssClass="templateType"
            onchange="adjustReportText()"
            name="templateID"
            listCssClass="templateType">
                <s:iterator value="{SOME MAP WITH KEY AND LIST OF VALUES}" var="TG" status="stat">
                    <s:optgroup label="%{key}" list="%{value}" listKey="templateId" listValue="templateName" ></s:optgroup>
                </s:iterator>
</s:select>
```

Comment: `listCssClass`: Property of list objects to get css class from. Without knowing what you're operating on, there's no way to diagnose anything.

Comment: My list objects do has a property with name "templateType" that contains a Css Class name fetched from DB

Comment: What my understanding about listCssClass attribute of <s:select > that it populates <option> tag with class attribute whose value is fetched from the list object from which that <option> tag is populated. Please correct me if I am wrong in my understanding.

Comment: AFAIK that's correct; my point was that there's no way to know if you're doing it right if the underlying data isn't demonstrated. Based on the JIRA created it seems like it's a bug.

Comment: Underlying data is just fine as I checked every possibility of the case that data is not present

Comment: Neat. When asking questions on SO it's important to incude all relevant information, otherwise there's no way to help. In this case since the ticket was created it's not relevant--my point, again, is that questions need to include enough information to help.